# Private Mac Address in iPhone

Tags: iphone, mac, privacy

When I connect to Wi-Fi in public spaces I use "private MAC address" for each connection. Does Apple have a database (and save) each of the private mac addresses used by my phone device or it's absolutely private?

Comment: This is written like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  To avoid having your question closed, please edit it to clearly state the problem your trying to solve.

Comment: You're wondering if your usage could be tracked back to you by getting Apple to divulge this?

Comment: You might want to check https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211227

Answer (score -1):

It will be temporary stored on device in certain logs like the WiFi connection log but that isn't transmitted to Apple or anything so it's pretty private to your device.

Comment: How can you be sure that this randomized address isn’t logged by Apple, even for diagnostic purposes?

Comment: Well you can't know for certain but I trust Apple not to have a huge database of random MAC addresses and timestamps linked to each device, maybe they do but very unlikely.  Think of the costs and for what benefit esp if they were ever found out to be doing this?

Comment: I suggest you look into a tool called Little Snitch and observe how many times your device contacts the mother ship.

Comment: I'm aware of it and others but this is iPhone and specifically related to randomized MAC addresses not iCloud, Update or App Store related things which all need to phone home, some of these comms contain your device's identifier which can be correlated back to the actual MAC address.  Not much point sending the randomized one unless you are specifically and manually troubleshooting WiFi connection issues.

Comment: We all can make assumptions about traffic, but as Allan already said: How can you be sure that this randomized address isn’t logged by Apple, even for diagnostic purposes? And if you can't (and, to be honest, nobody besides Apple can), isn't the answer than only a guess on how things might work?